# GCloud SQL Proxy cannot connect, unclear errors

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am having difficulty getting the gcloud sql proxy working on my local machine. I have gone through all the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) however I am getting the following errors. It is unclear to me what is actually going wrong. Important things to note, I am not using a service account, I am authenticating with my own account through ***gcloud auth login*** and I am following the TCP sockets steps.

**MySQL**

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

**GCloud SQL Proxy**

```
couldn't connect to "<my instance connection name>": googleapi: Error 400: This operation isn"t valid for this instance., invalidOperation
```

**GCloud Logs**

```
...  status: {
   code:  2     
   message:  "UNKNOWN"     
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp:  "2017-09-08T15:45:10.179994989Z"   
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"   
 timestamp:  "2017-09-08T15:45:04.289Z"   
}
```

Comment: Is it a first generation instance? Proxy connectivity only works for Second Generation instances.

Comment: yes, this is a first generation instance. That is a bummer. Good call, I see that requirement now in the docs, I don't know how I missed it before.

Comment: If you can make this into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason you are receiving this error message is because you are using a First Generation instance.

Proxy connectivity is only supported for Second Generation instances.